# How to create hidden form and get it's handle?

Tags: c#, forms, window-handles

I need to create hidden form and get it's handle to recieve messages by my console application. So, i tried this (not sure if actual form is running):

```
HiddenForm form = new HiddenForm();
```

And define form:

```
public partial class HiddenForm : Form
    {
        public HiddenForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Text = System.DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
            int currentWindowHandle = (int)FindWindow(null, title);
        }
    }
```

`currentWindowHandle` is getting `0`.

What am i doing wrong? And what is the right way?

For some reason, this don't work (new form is actually visible):

```
HiddenForm form = new HiddenForm();
Application.Run(form);
form.Visible = false;
```

And if i add in `HiddenForm` constructor this:

```
this.Visible = false;
```

Comment: Simply adding `this.CreateHandle();` is enough to force the native window to get created.  Maybe, various ways to screw this up, you can't get good help when you don't explain why you need this.

Comment: @HansPassant, explained i the beggining of the question.

Comment: Hmm, all you really explained is that you should be using a named pipe or socket or WCF instead of a window.

Comment: Hm... Thank you. But for emergency reasons (this is urgent educational project) window is most fast and easy solution (probably), as it only remains to define recieving method.

Comment: Also, `this.CreateHandle();` works! You may create same answer as it solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have Done it once. Like this.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

string title = "Microsoft Visual SourceSafe";
IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(null, title);
```

I get correctly the handle of the window. 
You can use Spy++ if you want to see more information about your form.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Well, i actually use it from the beginning. Just forget to mention method declaration.

Answer (score 0):

As @HansPassant mentioned it's enough just to do this to make everything right:

```
this.CreateHandle();
```